# Listview items selection error when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

i have a multi column listview to show stocks list a company. 
Code works when work on small data. (they fit the screen, scrolling don't need.)
but stock count as many as can't fit the screen. Below problems occured.

**1.** When a list item's details expand and scroll, another items selected, too. 
(for example i expand 3.stock, it selects 15.stock and 27.stock and 39.stock etc.etc. )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLRSJ.jpg

**2.** Another problem is details layout. Normally it have two tabs, but it shows too many tabs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2MyX.png

here is my adapter class:

```
    public class StockListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<EditText> editTextListMiktar = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    public ArrayList<String> stockNoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<LinearLayout> stockLayoutList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    private String stokNo;
    private Context context;
    private boolean isDetail;
    private String birim;
    private String processType;
    private String processNo;
    private Object kodTuru;
    private boolean clearAlsaDeta;
    public static String x;

    public StockListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list, Context context,String kodTuru, String processNo, String processType, boolean clearAlsaDeta) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.kodTuru = kodTuru;
        this.processNo = processNo;
        this.processType = processType;
        this.clearAlsaDeta = clearAlsaDeta;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView stockDetail;
        TextView stockNo;
        TextView stockCode;
        TextView stockName;
        Spinner stockBirim;
        TextView stockKdv;
        EditText stockMiktar;
        LinearLayout linearLayoutStockBase;
        LinearLayout linearLayoutStockDetail;
        TabHost TabHostStockDetail;
        ListView listviewDetailFiyat;
        ListView listviewDetailStok;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklistitems, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.linearLayoutStockBase = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutStockBase);
            stockLayoutList.add(holder.linearLayoutStockBase);
            holder.stockDetail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewStockDetail);
            holder.stockNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStockNo);
            holder.stockCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStockCode);
            holder.stockName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStockName);
            holder.stockBirim = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerStockBirim);
            holder.stockKdv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStockKdv);
            holder.stockMiktar = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextStockMiktar);
            editTextListMiktar.add(holder.stockMiktar);
            holder.linearLayoutStockDetail = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutStockDetails);
            holder.TabHostStockDetail = (TabHost) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tabHostStokList);
            holder.listviewDetailFiyat = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewStoklistDetailFiyat);
            holder.listviewDetailStok = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewStoklistDetailStok);
            holder.stockMiktar.setText("");
            // setMiktar(stokNo, processNo, holder.stockMiktar,
            // holder.linearLayoutStockBase);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        holder.stockNo.setText(map.get("StokNo"));
        stokNo = map.get("StokNo");
        stockNoList.add(stokNo);
        holder.stockCode.setText(map.get("StokCode"));
        holder.stockName.setText(map.get("StokName"));
        holder.stockKdv.setText(map.get("StokKdv"));
        holder.stockBirim.setAdapter(TableUtils.SpinnerAdapter(context, "SELECT BIRIM FROM STOKBIRI WHERE STOK_NO=" + stokNo, null));
        Functions.selectPrefItemsToSpinner(holder.stockBirim, map.get("StokBirim"));
        Functions.setSpinnerEnable(holder.stockBirim);
        holder.stockMiktar.setText("");

        holder.stockMiktar.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);

        // tab detail kısmının eklenmesi
        tabDetailSetup(stokNo, holder.TabHostStockDetail, holder.listviewDetailFiyat, holder.listviewDetailStok);

        // detay göster
        holder.stockDetail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!isDetail)
                {
                    holder.linearLayoutStockDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.stockDetail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_delete_expand);
                    isDetail = true;
                } else
                {
                    holder.linearLayoutStockDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.stockDetail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_plus);
                    isDetail = false;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.linearLayoutStockBase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!isDetail)
                {
                    holder.linearLayoutStockDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.stockDetail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_delete_expand);
                    isDetail = true;
                } else
                {
                    holder.linearLayoutStockDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.stockDetail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_plus);
                    isDetail = false;
                }

            }
        });

        holder.stockMiktar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                map.put("StokMiktar", s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                map.put("StokMiktar", s.toString());
            }
        });

        holder.stockBirim.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
            {
                birim = holder.stockBirim.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                map.put("StokBirim", birim);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

        public void tabDetailSetup(String stokNo, TabHost th, ListView lsFiyat, ListView lsStok)
    {
        th.setup();
        TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tabStoklistFiyat);
        spec1.setIndicator("Fiyatlar");
        TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Stoklar");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tabStoklistStok);
        th.addTab(spec1);
        th.addTab(spec2);
...      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't setup visibility of your linearLayoutStockDetail. ListView in android reuse view for rows. When you open detail view for row 3 and scroll bottom - android reuse your row number 3. You setup new values for text fields, but don't hide detail view.

The second problem, I guess, the same. You don't show tabDetailSetup method, but I think you add tabs everytime. You need to clear old tabs before.

Remember, when you are using convertView in adapter, you get old view with their own properies, which you set last time.

Comment: thanks a lot.. its work for detail problem, but how can i clear tabs?, i try tabHost.clearAllTab() method but it didn't work.

Comment: Show your tabDetailSetup method, I will try to help.

Comment: `public void tabDetailSetup(String stokNo, TabHost th, ListView
 lsFiyat, ListView lsStok)

 {
  th.setup();
  TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
  spec1.setContent(R.id.tabStoklistFiyat);
  spec1.setIndicator("Fiyatlar");
  TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
  spec2.setIndicator("Stoklar");
  spec2.setContent(R.id.tabStoklistStok);
  th.addTab(spec1);
  th.addTab(spec2);
...}`

Comment: Ok, here you get TabHost from convertView and add a 2 tabs. When you scroll down, you get this tabhost again and add another 2 tabs, and so on.
I think, that the best way for you is adding a tabs to tabhost when you create your view (when convertView == null in adapter). Then you create to tabs for all views for one time, and no need to create it again and again.

Comment: thanks i put the code in if(convertView==null){..} and its work..
but i have another problem... I enter a number to edittext, and scroll down, this clear the edittext when scroll up again, but i want to do enter count of stocks (all of them), and finally check it... how can i handle this problem ?

Comment: i mark your answer already.. thanks for help :) please mark my question as useful :)